# Sending JSON curl via Postman

Tags: json, postman

I am trying to send a request via Postman to API,
Below is the request type which is accepted by API,

```
curl https://api.shoonya.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth \
-d "jData={ \"apkversion\": \"1.0.0\", \"uid\": \"TRST\", \"pwd\": \"s3cur3Id\", \"factor2\":
\"31-08-2017\", \"imei\": \"134243434\", \"source\": \"API\"}“
```

When I send JSON via Postman[image], it throws the error `Invalid Input :  jData is not valid json object`

What is wrong with this request? Or how can I write JSON which has jData object?

--- Update..
Now I have imported curl in Postman, it gives the below auto inputs, But again it was not able to read `jData` as correct values. Seems it going as a string instead of JSON object.

[image]

Comment: remove the `jData = `

Comment: Then it end with ```"emsg": "Invalid Input :  jData is Missing."```

Comment: Then your API is not accapting `application/json` as body but something else `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `jData` should contain a json encoded string.

Comment: Typically you just paste your `curl` command into Postman and it will figure out what to do with this request. And you don't fiddle around with that

Comment: Importing the curl request in to Postman shows that the body content type used is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `application/json` you need to change your Postman request from `raw` to `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @derpirscher, can you help how should i write ```jData``` as json encoded string?

Comment: As I said, just paste your working `curl` request into postman and it will take care of the rest

Comment: @derpirscher, i made an update in my question, after pasting the curl in Postman, it gives urlencoded structure, but seems not able to read JSON objects correctly.

Comment: You have an invalid quote character `“`  as your very last character in your curl command. Postman will add this to the JSON string which makes it invalid. Replace this with a standard double quote `"`

Comment: @derpirscher, that has been corrected but still same, I will try to test another combination :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `"jData ="` from you message and try again.

Also its better to post a json file with curl as below

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @FILENAME DESTINATION
```

For example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json https://api.shoonya.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth
```

Comment: See the comments, OP already tried that. Seemingly the API doesn't accept `application/json` but `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` where one parameter is a JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Importing the curl command in to Postman (yes this would have been the easiest way for you to replicate it in Postman) sets the body content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `raw` as you have it your screenshot.

Change the content type and the request should work.

---

On a side note the body content as you currently have it is not valid JSON and would fail to be parsed as such. Postman even has unbderlined `jData=` with a red squiggly line`

[image: screenshot of Postman highlighting an error in JSON]

The valid/correct JSON would be:

```
{
  "apkversion": "1.0.0",
  "uid": "TRST",
  "pwd": "s3cur3Id",
  "factor2": "31-08-2017",
  "imei": "134243434",
  "source": "API"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Import button, and paste the Curl.

[image]

This is failing as you have an extra backslash after the URL, so its ignoring the data element.

Remove that and it should import fine.

> curl https://api.shoonya.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth -d "jData={"apkversion": "1.0.0", "uid": "TRST", "pwd": "s3cur3Id", "factor2":"31-08-2017", "imei": "134243434", "source": "API"}"

It should import as x-www-form-urlencoded.

[image]

Comment: did you got success response if you hit send?

Comment: No, and it doesn't work from curl either.  Not that I was expecting it to.  I would expect there to be some additional authentication.  Do you get a successful response from curl?  What API is this, and do you have the API specification?

Comment: this is API doc, https://shoonya.com/api-documentation#api-login

Comment: I tried that and get the same issue as you.  I don't think their example is correct, so I can only advise to get in touch with the supplier.